# Update UITableView after in-app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code in my `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` and I've confirmed that it runs the `.purchased` case when I complete a sandbox purchase.

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing, .deferred: break
        case .purchased, .restored:
            Settings.didPurchase = true
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
        case .failed: // other code here
        }
    }
}
```

The data source for my `UITableView` includes this function:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return Settings.didPurchase ? 3 : 4
}
```

While debugging, I confirmed that this function is called after I call `tableView.reloadData()` and that it returns `3` after the purchase. But, the view doesn't update to include the extra section. It only updates if I close the entire view and reload it after completing the purchase, in which case it triggers another table view reload and looks like it's supposed to.

My theory is that because the `UITableView` isn't the top-level view when I call `reloadData()` (it's covered by an alert from Apple saying that the purchase was successful), it's not updating the view, thinking it's not visible. But, is this reasonable? And either way, how can I fix my code so that the view updates as expected when the user completes a purchase?

Comment: did you debug your reload tableview method called ?

Comment: How many TableView do you have in the same ViewController?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that reloadData is called. I only have one TableView in the ViewController.